# jQuery Script by Showing DIV only loads one DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I have a Script, where I load diverent DIV's on a Dropdown selection. But, the problem is, it works only once. It doesn't work by all other divs, but only by one, the first on the list. The other DIV's won't load.

This is my code, in my eyes it seems correct.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").hide();
    $("#div3").hide(); 
    $("#div4").hide();
    $("#div5").hide();

   $("#pick_go").click(function() {
        var openId = $("#pick_select").val();

        $("#div1").hide();
        $("#div2").hide();
        $("#div3").hide(); 
        $("#div4").hide();
        $("#div5").hide();

        $("#div" + openId).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

The SELECT is pick_select, and the button which picks the choice is pick_go.

EDIT: The problem is that it doesn't show, however the code knows which DIV he needs to show, when trying it with a Alert.

The HTML For the selector DIV is following

```
 <select id="pick_select" style="height:40px; width:300px;">
 <option value="">Kies een Instelling</option>
    <option value="1">Wachtwoord veranderen</option>
    <option value="2">Veiligheidsvraag veranderen</option>
    <option value="3">PIN veranderen</option>
    <option value="4">Inlog Geschiedenis inzien</option>
    <option value="5">Account ter veiligheid blokkeren</option>
  </select>



<input type="submit" value="Openen" id="pick_go"style="height:40px; width:90px;" name="vp_picker_submit" class="submit" />
```

The code for the divs are this,

```
 <div class="habblet-container " id="div1" style="float:left; width: 560px;">
content
</div>
```

With only changing the ID.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your code, like your HTML?

Comment: You really need to put a class on all those elements and reduce your `hide()` calls to one each.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the HTML. Isher, I'm fairly new to jQuery, but I don't see what's going wrong here.

Comment: Can't reproduce problem? http://jsfiddle.net/g1u8m6sm/1/ all works fine. (yes, your code could be more compact, but, script is functional)

Comment: Check id's on your page.... this smells like 'multiple ids problem'' to me...

Comment: @nevermind, I Checked it. No multiple ids are found.

Comment: Hm... don't have idea then - if you can provide whole (html+js) context, maybe someone could help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine, here is a JSFiddle:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/nryvvL9s/
```

It's better to use classes than Id to hide all that divs

Here is the HTML I used:

```
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div id="div4">4</div>
<div id="div5">5</div>
<select id="pick_select" style="height:40px; width:300px;">
 <option value="">Kies een Instelling</option>
    <option value="1">Wachtwoord veranderen</option>
    <option value="2">Veiligheidsvraag veranderen</option>
    <option value="3">PIN veranderen</option>
    <option value="4">Inlog Geschiedenis inzien</option>
    <option value="5">Account ter veiligheid blokkeren</option>
  </select>



<input type="submit" value="Openen" id="pick_go"style="height:40px; width:90px;" name="vp_picker_submit" class="submit" />
```

Comment: Thanks. But still, the problem exists. Could it be another Script, which conflicts with this script?

Comment: can you show create a test page in your code like the jsFiddle I created?

Comment: I Use JSFiddle rarely, so I Tried, but there is nothing appearing, am I Implenting it wrong or is this the "Bug" we've been searching for?

Comment: do you use chrome or firefox debugger? is there an error showing at the console? give me more info to help you.